# datagridviewcomboboxcolumn databinding

Tags: winforms, data-binding, c#-2.0

I have a datagridviewcomboboxcolumn (ComboCol), that i add programmicaly to a datagridview.

I want my ComboCol to display in its dropdown the items of a IList, 
AND when an item from that list is selected, 
to assign that value to the property of an object on a **different** IList.

Is this possible? All I have been able to get so far is only half of the job.
I can display the items of a particular list by setting it as a datasource,
but when the item is selected i need to programicaly assign the proper value
to the desired object. Is there no way to do this automatically?

BTW, if I add the ComboCol to the datagridview, and then set the datagridview's datasource,
how does this affect the databinding of the ComboCol?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here is the answer.

In pseudocode:

> List PossibleValues
>
> List BoundObjects
>
> ComboCol.ValueMember --> Set to name of property of class in
>   PossibleValues ComboCol.DataPropertyName --> Set to name of property
>   of class in BoundObjects ComboCol.DisplayMember --> Set to name of
>   property of class in PossibleValues you wish to display
>
> DataGrid.Add(ComboCol)
>
> ComboCol.DataSource = PossibleValues
>   DataGrid.DataSource = BoundObjects